# Is there a Dataweave operator for Boolean validation of number falling between a given Range

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have a flow which calls two sub-flows using flow-refs and a choice conditional flow router.

The first condition in the when section is  `#[payload.num > 1000]`. When `True` this calls sub-flow-A.

when `false`, the NEXT when condition to check is `#[(payload.num < 1000) and (payload.num > 0)]`. When `True`, this calls sub-flow-B, else default.

Is there a way (any operator) to replace the usage `#[(payload.num < 1000) and (payload.num > 0)]` to something clean, short and simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in operator for that, your best option is to create a dw module in your classpath with that funtion. It's just a dwl file with that function and others if you want and no body.

```
// src/main/resources/MyModule.dwl
%dw 2.0

fun isBetween(numToCheck: Number, low: Number, high: Number) = do {
  (numToCheck > low) and (numToCheck < high)
}
```

and then you can just call it like:

```
#[MyModule::isBetween(payload.num, 0, 1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java

---
(0 to 1000) contains payload.num
```

Comment: Create array of thousands elements only to check one value? Custome function in the DW is the best shortcut for those who want this...

Comment: Same thought here Alex.

Comment: I am not kidding and i never meant this to be your solution. it was purely a suggestion to wrap your multi condition if into a possible way of doing this. You are more than welcome to not accept it . Purely was a way to show a possibility rather than a production grade code!!!!